# How to install flash player 11 debug on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: flash, plugins, debugging

I had hard time to figure this out, but I did it finally and I'm going to post an answer to my own question for others.

Comment: This doesn't work any more. I get this is not a valid NPAPI plugin error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So firstly install [Flash-Aid](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/flash-aid/) firefox plugin, and use it to install stable version of Flash Player. Next download "Linux Flash Player 11.2 Plugin content debugger" from [Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) (it doesn't matter if you have 64-bit Ubuntu). Put the proper files in /usr but libflashplayer.so file use to overwrite /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so .

But it's not all. Next install:

> sudo apt-get install nspluginwrapper ia32-libs

ia32-libs is required for nspluginwrapper to work in our case, and that was part that was hard to find for me.

Next:

> sudo nspluginwrapper -i
> /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so

Restart Firefox, and Flash Player 11 Debug should finally work. At least I can connect to it from IntelliJ IDEA.

I hope this will save some time for someone.

**Added: #1**
After process you should propably disable Flash-Aid extension, or it can overwrite your plugin.