# Unable to get flash player debugger to work in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: flash

I have tried installing flash player debugger for Linux and copied the files as mentioned in Readme file. But still not able to get debug option when right click on flash content. Any help would be appreciated.

Regards, Santosh

Answer (score 0):

Mr.Ramesh,have you consulted any website before?Follow the instructions of the following link.I hope it'll work.
[click here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214176/how-to-install-flash-player-11-debug-on-ubuntu-12-04)